# Is refilling rather than replacing a list ever a good strategy for speed, and why or why not?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of objects. I need to repeatedly update it to be a filtered version. When if ever should I accomplish this by refilling the existing list rather than creating a new list? That is, under what circumstances is object reuse more efficient than new object creation, in this setting? A simple experiments suggests "never", which surprised me.

To illustrate, consider the speed of the following (Python 3.8, Win 10). Is this easily explained?

```
import timeit

#assign ordinary list comprehension (2 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst=[x for x in lst if x>5000];",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
#assign with `list` instead of brackets (3 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst=list(x for x in lst if x>5000);",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
#reuse list, with generator (3.2 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst[:]=(x for x in lst if x>5000);",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
```

If it may reasonably be considered part of this question, I would also like to know why filter is always more than 30% slower.

```
#assign from spread filter (4.2 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst=[*filter(lambda x: x>5000, lst)];",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
#assign converted generator (4.4 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst=list(filter(lambda x: x>5000, lst));",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
#reuse list, fill from filter (4.6 seconds)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="lst[:]=filter(lambda x: x>5000, lst);",setup="lst=list(range(10000));",number=10000))
```

Comment: `filter` is slower in part because you call the function on every iteration, function-call overhead is not insignificant

Comment: Note, in the `list[:] = <whatever>` form, I'm pretty sure under the hood `list(<whatever>)` is called, so that explains why it is so similar to `lst = list(generator)`

Comment: Anyway, for a `list` object, my intuition says that practically never is it more efficient to re-size an existing object. Essentially, the underlying buffer will almost certainly have to be re-allocated anyway, so the big work is almost the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In this case, the "resizing" is always a shrinking. Will this still lead to reallocation? (And how do we know?)

Comment: @ggorlen Profiling revealed that I'm spending a surprising amount of time on this. I had assumed reusing the list would be best (because it avoids object creation and never needs a longer list). I'm not sure what is "speculative" here...

Comment: @ggorlen The question speaks of lists,not arbitary objects. Also, am I wrong to believe that `lst[:]=mylist` reuses `lst` (i.e., the existing object)? I rather doubt that. Certainly `lst` still points to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's not so much the filling of the list as much as item creation which is relevant. List operations are very fast and efficient and I would never assume these are problematic unless prompted by a specific edge case.

Additionally python is a garbage collected language, meaning that after the array is (implicitly) dereferenced it'll get cleaned up eventually. This effectively spread out the load of removing the stuff as long as you have enough memory.